# Not able to access html extent reports in Jenkins

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I can't access the html extent reports in Jenkins. I am getting the below console output:

> ```
> [JENKINS] Archiving C:\Eclipse Mars 4.5.2\eclipse\@user.home\Eclipse Mars\Workspace\Supplier_Admin\Supplier_Integration_MyAdmin\Supplier_Admin\target\Supplier_Admin-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to com.Supplier/Supplier_Admin/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/Supplier_Admin-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
> channel stopped
> [htmlpublisher] Archiving HTML reports...
> [htmlpublisher] Archiving at PROJECT level D:\Supplier Repository\MyAdmin to C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Supplier Integration MyAdmin Local\htmlreports\HTML_Report
> Finished: UNSTABLE
> ```

But getting  below error when trying to access the report:

```
HTTP ERROR 404
Problem accessing /job/Supplier%20Integration%20MyAdmin%20Local/HTML_Report/index1.htm. Reason:
    Not Found
```

**Tried even with both .html and .htm extensions**

Comment: Can you manually confirm that the file was actually created?

Answer (score 0):

Need to configure HTML **export path** so the HTML report gets generated first, then only you can archive the report to your suggested path, Please confirm you report is exported in a mentioned path, then configure your **HTML directory to archive** path from **Publish HTML report** plugin.